# C++ way to override basic_string

Tags: c++, templates, stl, alloc

I am using gcc 2.95.3 to support a legacy system that uses multi-threaded application. STL implementation for basic_string is not threadsafe and STL implementation for `__default_alloc_template<false, 0>::allocate(unsigned int)` too. If I could ovverride these by  providing my own implementation that would ensure mutual exclusion through semaphore lock and unlock, and call the original function through `dlsym` search?

Comment: It's a little confusing what the exact question is. If you provide your own implementation of string then what, will it be thread safe?  Is it worth the effort?

Comment: @Ron did you know that the stl fights in the bar with anyone that inherits from it?  (c)

Comment: [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) allows you to provide a custom allocator as a template argument. You can use this to provide a thread-safe allocator. `std::basic_string` is not designed to be thread safe however. In any case, you will need to provide your own synchronization.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux when std::string is used, that, in turn, std::basic_string, how and where to pass the custom allocator? If I could pass custom thread-safe allocator, that would serve my purpose, please guide

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658341/using-a-custom-allocator-in-stdstring-to-re-use-an-already-allocated-char-buff, it says std::string cannot be made use a different allocator, is there any way?

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana No, you can't change the allocator is you are using `std::string` already. You would have to use `std::basic_string`. `std::string` *is* a `std::basic_string`, so the interface is identical. However, you would need to change ever instance of the type `std::string`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux how to override basic_string's allocator and use?